# autocomplete using lucene how to discard certain terms for searching

Tags: java, lucene

I am building an application that requires a *auto-complete search* feature. I am using `Lucene 4.2.1` implementation and I am making use of `RegexQuery` to make the search for autocomplete. My requirement is that when a user puts in a search query with multiple terms *(e.g cafe coffee day)* the type in of any term should be considered for search only when there are atleast three letters in that term.

for example: if the user has already typed in the word *cafe* and now started to type *coffee* but has     only gone far til *c* or *co* the searcher should not consider these tokens for regex query.

Please suggest how can I achieve the desired effect? is there a way I can specify something like *term validation* to tell the either the `QueryParser` to ignore the terms with less than 3 letters in the generated query or to the `searcher` for a given `Query`.

Comment: I don't think "term validation" is within the scope of Lucene. Why don't you validate/parse the terms in your application and strip the invalid terms before passing them to Lucene?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than cobbling together an auto-complete with a regex query, I would recommend taking a look at the [Lucene Suggest API](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/suggest/).

Aside from that, you don't really say much about how your current implementation works.  However, if you don't want to search when only two letters of the current word have been typed, then simply don't make the call to search.

If you are saying you DO want to search, but want to ignore all words with 2 or less chars, you might benefit from using a standard, tokenized query, and applying an analyzer with a [LengthFilter](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/miscellaneous/LengthFilter.html).  If you are not aware of how to put together a custom [Analyzer](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/StandardAnalyzer.html), then working from the example in the Lucene docs, something like:

```
Analyzer analyzer = new Analyzer() {
 @Override
  protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents(String fieldName, Reader reader) {
    Tokenizer source = new FooTokenizer(reader); //ex. StandardAnalyzer
    TokenStream filter = new FooFilter(source); //ex. StandardFilter, LowercaseFilter, StopFilter, etc.
    filter = new BarFilter(filter);
    filter = new LengthFilter(true, filter, 3, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    return new TokenStreamComponents(source, filter);
  }
};
```

As far as a Regex query, if you need to transform "`this and that a.*`" to "`this and that.*`", you will need to implement that transformation yourself.

Comment: thanks femtoRgon.. I think it seems that slight modifications to the  above code might work for me... and I'll do explore the suggest API. thnx for the `suggest`ion.

Answer (score 0):

you can also create a custom query parser by extending the existing Query Parser classes